# SQL Profiler 2000 will not pause or stop

Tags: sql-server-2000, profiler

Has anyone seen the issue with SQL Profiler 2000 where you cannot pause or stop a trace?  The only way I can stop it, is by doing a control - alt - delete and then end the application process.  This just randomly started happening.  Also the pause and stop buttons grey out.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem with Profiler on a Windows 2003 Server Virtual Machine running SQL Server 2000 SP4. Increasing the allocated memory made no difference.

Verify that your server name is correct in the sysservers table in the master database. A common mistake when changing a SQL Server machine name is not to update the sysservers table.

Profiler resolves the server name from sysservers table if you enter "." or "(local)" to connect to the SQL Server when creating a trace. You can check the Trace SQL Server name after connecting on the General tab of Trace Properties or on the caption bar of the trace itself.

If the displayed name is is not the actual server name then you can expect Profiler to misbehave as described above.

Work-around: If you connect using the actual server name or "127.0.0.1" instead of "." or "(local)" then the Trace SQL Server name should display correctly, and Profiler should allow you to stop/pause/run the selected trace.

Resolution: Make sure [all the applicable steps have been performed](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_change_server_name.asp) after changing the SQL Server machine name.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen consistently on some (virtual) machines - clicking the stop button causes it to grey-out (but not enable start etc), but seem to wait forever in the "stopping" state without actually stopping.  Unfortunately, I don't have a fix.

However, the systems where this happen were all fairly low-resource VPCs.  The fact that this always happened for the VPCs, but never for my desktop system made me suspicious that it may be related to low memory availability, or else something about the VPC environment, but I never confirmed this for certain.

At the time, I worked around it by connecting remotely, running profiler on my own machine.  If this is a low-spec machine / VPC, it may be worth trying this, or else closing all apps on the machine before using profiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more info to help you here.

- Are you running it on a virual machine?
- How long are you running it for?
- Give us example of what your using SQL Profiler to trace. (SQL Code, DB's tables etc?)
- When it will not pause or stop run **sp_who** in Query Analyser to see if anything is being blocked
- Whats your hardware setup on the server? (memory/processors etc)

Comment: we are running it on our database server which has p4 2.4 ghz processor with 3.6 gb ram on Windows 2000.

I filter by database, run it for not even 30 seconds and try and hit pause or stop; it then greys out and continues to trace..

I'll run sp_who and send an update.

Many thanks for all the comments!

Comment: I have just ran sp_who after hitting stop on SQL Server Profiler.  What would I be looking for?  I see the SA account has a checkpoint sleep and lock monitor.  Would either of those indicate anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yup happens to me all the time - the easiest way to get it back is to kill the connection.

Comment: This didn't use to happen.  It's really inconvenient not being about to pause or stop.  Thanks for confirming that I am not the only person experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you work with virtual machine - 
enter `SQL Server 127.0.0.1` instead of `"local"`

Answer (score 0):

How patient are you being? Is this a few seconds, few minutes, half an hour? What amount of data are you talking about and over what sort of connection.

I have had to wait for the profiler to "catch up" before when viewing a database with very high usage.

I have also had to wait for it to respond if I've been profiling over a slower vpn connection.

A combination of the two can have you waiting for some time.